# If I have Charm of Wisdom and Lore of Escape, do I add my Wisdom modifier twice to Bluff checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, stacking, inquisitor

In the character generation process for the Inquisitor class, I was faced with a question, the answer to which I'm not entirely sure.

I used [Conversion Inquisition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/inquisitions/inquistions-paizo/conversion-inquisition/), which grants me:

> **Charm of Wisdom (Ex)**: You use your Wisdom modifier instead of your Charisma modifier when making Bluff, Diplomacy, and Intimidate checks.

After that, I added the archetype [Heretic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/inquisitor-archetypes-paizo/heretic/) for the Inquisitor, which grants me:

> **Lore of Escape (Ex)**: At 1st level, the heretic uses every trick she knows to escape those now pursuing her. She adds her Wisdom modifier on Bluff and Stealth skill checks in addition to the normal ability score modifiers.

For **Bluff** checks, this would mean adding a **Wisdom** modifier twice. Is that allowed by the rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Officially, the inquisitor adds his Wisdom modifier once

The [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9sgk) includes this exchange:

> **Question:** Do ability modifiers from the same ability stack? For instance, can you add the same ability bonus on the same roll twice using two different effects that each add that same ability modifier?
>
> **Answer:** No. An ability bonus, such as "Strength bonus", is considered to be the same source for the purpose of bonuses from the same source not stacking. However, you can still add, for instance “a deflection bonus equal to your Charisma modifier” and your Charisma modifier. For this purpose, however, the paladin's untyped "bonus equal to her Charisma bonus (if any) on all saving throws" from divine grace is considered to be the same as "Charisma bonus (if any)", and the same would be true for any other untyped "bonus equal to her [ability score] bonus" constructions.

However, this ruling is considered ill-conceived by some (including me). Unless building a character for Pathfinder Society play, discuss with the GM ignoring it.